# Xamarin - Iterate over all audio files on an Android device

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, audio, xamarin.android

Simple as it is, couldn't find any related question.
Is there a method for iterating over all audio files? 
The way music apps like Music Player, Google Play Music work..

Comment: You are looking for "ContentResolver", review the "Retrieving media from a ContentResolver" section: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer as the document takes you through the entire process of querying/playing media.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from @SushiHangover provided the answer, namely [ContentResolver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver).